# Notification or Alerts Framework for .NET C# Component

Tags: c#, components, notifications

I am looking for a Notification or Alerts framework that can be used in my application as a separate module, I can just use the features of the framework.Are there any good ones?.

I need frameworks that dont use to much dll from other vendors to do some jobs..just connected to .net framework dlls

notifcations like email as basic...

Comment: I think abmv is asking for a third-party library to support sending out email alerts or notifications. He doesn't want something that leverages unmanaged code - rather, something built in pure .net. Since SSRS 2008 has been deprecated, I'm looking for something like this myself.

Comment: actually there are two on codeplex but they come with the price of external or depending on some aop stuff...

Answer (score 0):

We are using log4net and have found great flexibility with it. We also have our own wrapper class which is used in all of our projects allowing us to use static methods for writing to the defined logs. Log4net comes with one dll, and of course our wrapper dll. It is easy to extend this for added functionality, our wrapper class now allows us to write to the windows event logs if/when needed.

There are plenty of examples of how to implement log4net, and it provides alot of ways to write/send log information:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Example implementation of our wrapper:

```
Log.Error("Message", this);
Log.Error("Message", Exception, this);
Log.Error("Message", Exception, Type);
Log.Info("Message", this);
Log.Warn("Message", this);
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like log4Net? or a messaging queue system, sks MSMQ

Answer (score -1):

the microsoft enterprise logging module of the enterprise framework can be configured for your purpose. it supports a variety of channels including email and trace file. it can be reconfigured through a change in the configuration file of your app.